# Universal IR Remote Android in Android 12

Tags: android, frequency

I'm creating a universal IR remote android app with android studio.
I make a remote for TCL android tv and it worked perfectly.
I have collected all the frequency codes for almost 70% of Remotes.
My question is. is IR signal will work with different frequencies for all. If I change the frequency and pass the TCL IR signal code it will work? ... if not then suggest to me the best database for the IR signal... And how can I convert the Ir signal from HexaDecimal to decimal code?

private val freq: Int =  38380

private fun volumeDown() {

```
    val btn_VOLUME_DOWN_codes = intArrayOf(

        3796, 3926, 468, 1950, 494, 1950, 494, 1950, 494, 1976, 494, 988, 494, 962, 494, 1976, 494, 988, 494, 1950, 494, 1950, 494, 1950, 494, 962, 494, 962, 494, 962, 494, 962, 494, 962, 494, 1950, 494, 1976, 494, 962, 494, 1976, 494, 988, 494, 988, 494, 962, 494, 1950, 494, 7228, 3848, 3926, 468, 1950, 494, 1950, 494, 1950, 494, 1976, 494, 988, 520, 962, 494, 1976, 494, 962, 494, 1976, 468, 1950, 494, 1976, 494, 988, 494, 988, 494, 988, 494, 988, 494, 962, 494, 1950, 494, 1976, 494, 962, 494, 1976, 494, 988, 494, 988, 494, 988, 494, 1924, 494, 7228, 3822, 3926, 468, 1950, 494, 1950, 494, 1950, 494, 1976, 494, 988, 494, 988, 494, 1976, 494, 962, 494, 1950, 494, 1950, 494, 1976, 520, 962, 494, 962, 494, 962, 494, 962, 494, 962, 494, 1950, 494, 1976, 494, 962, 494, 1976, 494, 988, 494, 988, 494, 962, 494, 1950, 494, 7254
    )


    irService?.transmit(freq,btn_VOLUME_DOWN_codes)

}
```

Comment: https://github.com/j4velin/IR-Remote/blob/master/app/src/main/java/de/j4velin/ir_remote/MainActivity.java

Comment: if anyone is stuck in IR Remote then go with the above link.